# Defacing the Title on Spree Admin pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I would like to change the title on spree admin pages, and i`m trying to do that on deface:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/admin/shared/_header.html.erb',
                     :name => 'override',
                     :replace => 'title') do
  '<title>MyOnly Administrativo</title>'
end
```

This is not working at all....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of work later I figured out what works, that is:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/admin/shared/_head',
                     :name => 'override',
                     :replace_contents => 'title',
                     :text => 'MyOnly Administrativo')
```